# How do I change the color of my active nav-link to another color?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How do I change the original color (blue) to something else like grey?

```
<div class="col-md-4 ftco-animate py-5 nav-link-wrap aside-stretch">
     <div class="nav flex-column nav-pills" id="v-pills-tab" role="tablist">
         <a class="nav-link px-4 active" id="v-pills-room-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-room" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-room" aria-selected="true"><i class="fas fa-bed"></i> Rooms</a>
         <a class="nav-link px-4" id="v-pills-event-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-event" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-event" aria-selected="false"><i class="fab fa-dribbble"></i> Events</a>
         <a class="nav-link px-4" id="v-pills-dining-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-dining" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-dining" aria-selected="false"><i class="fas fa-cocktail"></i> Dining</a>
         <a class="nav-link px-4" id="v-pills-policy-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-policy" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-policy" aria-selected="false"><i class="fas fa-feather-alt"></i> Policy</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to override the existing styles , like this
a:focus{
color:grey;
}

Answer (score 0):

These are the states of the link to style as per your need,

```
a:link - a normal, unvisited link
a:visited - link the user has visited
a:hover - link when the user mouses over it
a:active - link the moment it is clicked
```

This would be applied to all the `a` tags, if you want to do for the specific class as you have you can use the className and use this properties.

```
.nav-link px-4:active {
  color:grey;
};
```

This link can give you more idea and you would be able to test it there,

[CSS links](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp)

Answer (score 0):

I see, you are using bootstrap, so you can use [bootstrap colors](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/colors/), for example **bg-success**:

```
<a class="nav-link px-4 active bg-success" id="v-pills-room-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#v-pills-room" role="tab" aria-controls="v-pills-room" aria-selected="true"><i class="fas fa-bed"></i> Rooms</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change it via css.

```
.active {
  color: #DCDCDC;   
}
```